# Time taken for each task in celery

Tags: django, celery

**Doubt 1:-**

I am currently using **celery** for **asynchronous tasks**. In my computer currently, the function is passed to 8 workers.

I wanted to know how much time is taken for processing each worker's result.

Also, I have heard that in celery, for loops and print statements are not going to work, is this true?

**Doubt 2:-**

I initially tried celery outside of my Django project and now I want to i**ntegrate into my Django project**. I have seen that there is a separate process for setting up celery especially in Django. Will it work if I use my previous normal celery stuff in my Django project or do I have to do it in Django way like **creating __int__.py file etc,..**?

I maintained a **task.py** and in **views.py** I will am importing the function from the task and wrote a separate function in **views.py which uses delay() function for passing** the data to task.py to run it asynchronously.

Comment: "I have heard that in celery, for loops and print statements are not going to work, is this true?" => I don't know where you've seen this...

Comment: "Will it work if I use my previous normal celery stuff " => if you mean the tasks you have already implemented, then yes of course it will work. This is, basically, just Python code.

Comment: "do I have to do it in Django way like creating __init__.py file etc" => how does this relates ? `__init__.py` files are a Python stuff, not a Django one, and if you don't know this nor what those files are for, I kindly (but very strongly) suggest you do the [full official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) (nb: just make sure you select the correct python version - the one you're using for this project).

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your **Doubt 2**:

You're correct, adding celery in you `init.py` is essential:

```
# __init__.py

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Another important item (At least in how I have learned to use Celery) is to add a `celery.py` to the project folder and add something similar to following. These could also be added to your `settings.py`, but I like the separation.

```
# celery.py

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'your_project.settings')

app = Celery('your_project')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Finally, your `settings.py` will be able to understand your celery commands. If you use this format, your celery commands require CELERY_ as a prefix. My example relates to utilizing a backend server to house the celery actions. Here I display how to utilize [Redis](https://redis.io) for such activities. My example for production works for one of my current projects hosted on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/home).

```
# settings.py

# Celery
# For Development and local Redis server
# CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
# CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'

# For Production
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
```